# Использование интерфейса и синглтона

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, интерфейс, абстрактная-фабрика

Здравствуйте, назрел такой вопрос.
Как с точки зрения ООП правильнее сделать синглтон для какого-либо класса, на который все "смотрят" через интерфейс? То есть есть у меня в проекте, например, ResourceManager, есть его реализация ResourceManagerImpl, если использовать это как

```
ResourceManager manager = ResourceManagerImpl.getInstance();
```

то мой класс будет зависеть от реализации, что категорически не хочется. То есть если я захочу поменять менеджер, придётся лезть внутрь всех классов, которые его используют.
Другой конец палки - это создать общую фабрику на весь проект, которая будет возвращать сущности для таких интерфейсов, но это получается уже подобие Божественного объекта, что тоже не очень хорошо. Какие подходы используете вы и почему?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос то у меня для этих целей используется внедрение зависимостей

Comment: А почему для описанного случая класс будет зависеть от реализации?

Comment: Сделайте просто `IResourceManager manager = ResourceManagerImpl.getInstance();` и будете зависеть от интерфейса. Ессна при смене надо будет возвращать другой инстанс, но менять придётся только `ResourceManagerImpl`.

Comment: @Monk Вот именно про это я говорю, это - плохая практика. В терминах ООП мы зависим от класса ResourceManagerImpl, во что это выливается - представьте, что во всём проекте вы повсеметсно писали  'ResourceManagerImpl.getInstance();' , тогда если вы захотите поменять его на 'ResourceManagerDummy', вам придётся идти по всему проекту и заменять все эти вызовы. Решение - действительно,   dependency injection, как было сказано выше, прочитал - очень удобная штука.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Зачем менять `ResourceManagerImpl` на `ResourceManagerDummy` если можно просто поменять внутри класса `ResourceManagerImpl` реализацию на новую и всё? Можно подумать, вы менять будете частично.